# Change loop execution in angular js

Tags: html, angularjs

Is there any way I can alternate the loop execution in the below HTML? I have 2 *div* elements to print the properties *Name* and *Age*. If I run the below code, It is printing the name first and Age second. This yields output like below:

```
John
Jessie
Johanna
25
30
28
```

There should not be any change in HTML. One div is for Name and another one is for Age.I want output like below.

```
John
25
Jessie
30
Johanna
28
```

Below is the HTML for sample which I created.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<div id="name" ng-repeat="x in friends">
{{x.name}}
</div>
<div id="name" ng-repeat="x in friends">

{{x.age}}
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.friends = [
    {name:'John', age:25, gender:'boy'},
    {name:'Jessie', age:30, gender:'girl'},
    {name:'Johanna', age:28, gender:'boy'}
  ];
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end as the following.

```
<div id="name" ng-repeat-start="x in friends">
{{x.name}}
</div>
<div id="name" ng-repeat-end>
{{x.age}}
</div>
```

This will create the divs the way you wanted.

This will be the full code

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

    <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <div id="name" ng-repeat-start="x in friends">
    {{x.name}}
    </div>
    <div id="name" ng-repeat-end>

    {{x.age}}
   </div>

     <script>
     var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
      app.controller("myCtrl",     function($scope) {
  $scope.friends = [
   {name:'John', age:25, gender:'boy'},
    {name:'Jessie', age:30, gender:'girl'},
    {name:'Johanna', age:28, gender:'boy'}
   ];
   });
  </script>

  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Let me try this. Thanks

Comment: yeah this should be the answer, i really could not think of it :)

Comment: Hey once i reach office, i will try and let you know. If it works, i will mark this as correct answer :) Thanks a lot

Comment: @sam for a detailed explanation, including a reference to the documentation and a working example snippet, please see my answer

Answer (score 0):

You don't need nested ng-repeat, just use the first one and just do this

```
<div id="name" ng-repeat="x in friends">
{{x.name}}  {{x.age}}
</div>
```

**DEMO**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<div id="name" ng-repeat="x in friends">
{{x.name}} {{x.age}}
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.friends = [
    {name:'John', age:25, gender:'boy'},
    {name:'Jessie', age:30, gender:'girl'},
    {name:'Johanna', age:28, gender:'boy'}
  ];
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry. we should not change the html. we should have 2 divs.

Comment: I have just given a sample. Real scenaio is entirely different. we have 2 divs. One div will show a product name and price and another div will show a product description with other specifications.  For sample purpose, i have just given a dummy html.

Comment: post your sample product json, in this case you dont need two divs. in the second scenario you can have two divs.

Comment: Json is just similar to the above one. That's how we got the html from a client.They will not change the html. Need to achieve using angularjs

Comment: if you really need a div there just embed it with another div <div>{{x.name}}
    </div>
    <div>
      {{x.age}}
    </div>

Comment: I said scenaio is entirely different. we have 2 divs. I am gonna get the json as above. One div will show name and price. It will have a link "More info". when we click on it, It will show open a popup at the bottom of this div and will show a description and other specifications. hope you understand. Everything is taken care using bootstrap. Hope you understand.

Answer (score 0):

Use **ng-repeat-start** (a special syntax of the [ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) directive) to start the repeat and **ng-repeat-end** to finish it.

> #### Special repeat start and end points
>
> <sub>To repeat a series of elements instead of just one parent element, ngRepeat (as well as other ng directives) supports extending the range of the repeater by defining explicit start and end points by using **ng-repeat-start** and **ng-repeat-end** respectively. The **ng-repeat-start** directive works the same as **ng-repeat**, but will repeat all the HTML code (including the tag it's defined on) up to and including the ending HTML tag where **ng-repeat-end** is placed.</sub><sup>[1](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)</sup>

Employing those directives with your code would look like this:

```
<div ng-repeat-start="x in friends" id="name{{x.name}}">
{{x.name}}
</div>
<div ng-repeat-end>
{{x.age}}
</div>
```

Note that the *id* attribute was changed to contain `{{x.name}}`. That is because "*The **id** [global attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes) defines a unique identifier (ID) which must be unique in the whole document*" <sup>[2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id)</sup>.

See this demonstrated below.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.friends = [{
      name: 'John',
      age: 25,
      gender: 'boy'
    },
    {
      name: 'Jessie',
      age: 30,
      gender: 'girl'
    },
    {
      name: 'Johanna',
      age: 28,
      gender: 'boy'
    }
  ];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat-start="x in friends" id="name{{x.name}}">
    {{x.name}}
  </div>
  <div ng-repeat-end>
    {{x.age}}
  </div>
</body>
```

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat</sub>

<sup>2</sup><sub>https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id</sub>

Comment: There is no such core directive as `ng-id`.

Comment: I knew that but didn't see any errors when trying to use it. Initially I used it because it appeared not to work with just `id` but now I see it does work. I have removed the prefix.